# Working with android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm new to android and the positioning elements are way different than as it is for web.
So What I want to do is this:

```
Login: ______  
Password: _____
```

What I can get is this, by setting the linearLayout to vertical orientation:

```
Login:  
__  
Password:  
__
```

Or this, with horizontal orientation:

```
Login:_____Password:_____
```

How may I mix it and achieve what I need?

Current code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Login:"
        android:textSize="14pt"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/loginText"/>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Senha:"
        android:textSize="14pt"/>  

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/passText"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A good practice for a mobile device would be to use a text hint https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setHint(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 2):

Nest your linearlayouts.  Have a vertical top level linear layout, with 2 horizontal linear layouts inside, each of which does one line of your output.

Comment: Extremely normal.  Layouts within layouts are common, and necessary for many designs.  If you go too deep its a bad idea, but 2 or 3 levels is fine.  If you find yourself at 5 or 6, you may want to move to something else.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use `sp` instead of `pt` for `android:textSize`.

You can achieve your expected layout using Nested `LinearLayout` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Login:"
            android:textSize="14pt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Senha:"
            android:textSize="14pt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**However a good practice would be to use ConstraintLayout, which reduces the view hierarchy, as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login:"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/loginText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Senha:"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/passText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The good practice would be to use ConstraintLayout. Also use `sp` instead of `pt` for `textSize`

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro check the udpated answer

Answer (score 1):

Usually on mobile you do not need to use label like in web. `setHint` on `EditText` should be enough to make the purpose of the fields clear for your users.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"/>

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use the material text field if you want something like a label to be always there, https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

you can use **linear layout** for each block like  **text view and edit text and set linear layout orientation horizontal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Username"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice if you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) to decrease `layout hierarchy`. Otherwise, you can use nested `LinearLayout`.